# gatsby and gatsby-theme-docz

Tags: gatsby, docz

I have a blog built in gatsby. I'd also like to use `docz` to document my react components. However, I can't seem to get both to work in my app. Whenever I run `$ yarn start` I just get my docz page and not my blog. How can I run my blog with `$ yarn start` and still run my docz stuff with some other command? Thanks!

```js
// gatsby-config.js
require('dotenv').config();
const colors = require('./src/utils/colors');

const { GRAPHQL_URL } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'blog',
    description: "my blog",
    author: 'me',
    siteUrl: 'https://www.me.com',
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-typescript',
    'gatsby-plugin-tslint',
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-tsconfig-paths`,
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-graphql',
      options: {
        typeName: 'GCMS',
        fieldName: 'gcms',
        url: GRAPHQL_URL,
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    'gatsby-plugin-emotion',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'images',
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-manifest',
      options: {
        name: 'blog',
        short_name: 'blog',
        start_url: '/',
        background_color: '#ffffff',
        theme_color: colors.Blue,
        display: 'minimal-ui',
        icon: 'src/images/icon.png',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typography`,
      options: {
        pathToConfigModule: `src/utils/typography`,
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',
    'gatsby-theme-docz',
  ],
};
```

```
// doczrc.js
export default {
  files: ['**/*.{md,markdown,mdx}'],
  dest: '.docz/theme/dist',
  typescript: true,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to **NOT** use `gatsby-theme-docz` and to just install `docz` standalone! I now run docz with `yarn docz dev`